# How to get the webpage using pyqt5?

Tags: javascript, python, pyqt5

I want to get the webpage using `pyqt5`.

The url is `https://land.3fang.com/LandAssessment/b6d8b2c8-bd4f-4bd4-9d22-ca49a7a2dc1f.html`.

The webpage will generate two values with javascript.

Just input `5` in the text box and press the red button.

Two values in red will be returned.

Please refer to the image.

The code below is used to get the webpage.

However, I wait for a long time and there is no response.

What should I change in my code?

Thank you very much.

[image]

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

class Render(QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.html = None
        self.first_pass = True
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebEngineView.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._load_finished)
        self.load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def _load_finished(self, result):
        if self.first_pass:
            self._first_finished()
            self.first_pass = False
        else:
            self._second_finished()

    def _first_finished(self):
        self.page().runJavaScript('document.getElementById("txtDistance").value = "5";')
        self.page().runJavaScript("void(0)")
        self.page().runJavaScript("CheckUserWhere();")

    def _second_finished(self):
        self.page().toHtml(self.callable)

    def callable(self, data):
        self.html = data
        self.app.quit()

url = "https://land.3fang.com/LandAssessment/b6d8b2c8-bd4f-4bd4-9d22-ca49a7a2dc1f.html"
web = Render(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(web.html, 'html.parser')
element = soup.find('div', {'id':"divResult"})
df = pd.read_html(str(element))
```

[image]

Comment: No, the code cannot produce what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have several misconceptions:

- When js is executed, the page is not reloaded, so the _second_finished function will never be called.
- If you do not want to show the window then it is better to use QWebEnginePage.

Considering the above the html that is obtained is:

```html
<div class="p8-5" id="divResult" style="display:block;">
<div align="center" display="block" id="rsloading" style="display: block;">
<img src="//img2.soufunimg.com/qyb/loading.gif"/>
                        正在为您加载数据...
                    </div>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tablebox01" display="none" id="tbResult" style="display: none;" width="600">
<tbody><tr>
<td style="width:260px;"><span class="gray8">建设用地面积：</span>14748平方米</td>
<td style="width:340px;"><span class="gray8">所在城市：</span>山西省 长治市 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span class="gray8">规划建筑面积：</span>51617平方米</td>
<td><span class="gray8">土地评估楼面价：</span><b class="redc00 font14" id="_bpgj">867.61</b> 元/平方米</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span class="gray8">容积率：</span>大于1并且小于或等于3.5</td>
<td><span class="gray8">土地评估总价：</span><b class="redc00 font14" id="_bSumPrice">4478.34</b> 万元</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span class="gray8">规划用途：</span>住宅用地</td>
<td><span class="gray8">推出楼面价：</span>27.51元/平方米</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>
```

So the simplest thing to do is to filter by the ids "_bpgj" and "_bSumPrice"

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Render(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.html = ""
        self.first_pass = True
        self.app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        super(Render, self).__init__()
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._load_finished)
        self.loadProgress.connect(print)
        self.load(QtCore.QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def _load_finished(self, result):
        if result:
            self.call_js()

    def call_js(self):
        self.runJavaScript('document.getElementById("txtDistance").value = "5";')
        self.runJavaScript("void(0)")
        self.runJavaScript("CheckUserWhere();")
        self.toHtml(self.callable)

    def callable(self, data):
        self.html = data
        self.app.quit()

url = "https://land.3fang.com/LandAssessment/b6d8b2c8-bd4f-4bd4-9d22-ca49a7a2dc1f.html"
web = Render(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(web.html, 'html.parser')
_bpgj = soup.find('b', {'id':"_bpgj"}).string
_bSumPrice = soup.find('b', {'id':"_bSumPrice"}).string
print(_bpgj, _bSumPrice)
```

Output:

```
867.61 4478.34
```

Comment: I ran your program twice and I got the two results:


0
70
100
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\program.py", line 277, in <module>
    _bpgj = soup.find('b', {'id':"_bpgj"}).string
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'

and the second is

0
22
70
100
-- --

Comment: @Chan Maybe you have some activated proxy, or some other restriction or problem of your network, I have tested it with the latest version of pyqt5: 5.12.1 https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5 and PyQtWebEngine: 5.12.1: https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqtwebengine/download and it works correctly. Try updating your libraries.

Comment: @Chan some feedback?

Comment: I  uninstalled pyqt5 and pyqtwebengine and then reinstalled them. There are no problems with `from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets` now. However, the python IDLE editor restarts when executing the program. I am searching the web to solve this problem. Any ideas?

Comment: @Chan IDLE is not the best option to use a library that has an event-loop as PyQt since it will block the event-loop of the same IDLE. So professionally you should not use IDLE.

Comment: I used jupyter notebook too but still the same.

Comment: Sorry, where to add `%gui qt`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191425/discussion-between-chan-and-eyllanesc).